# How to convert a linking list to an dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

I created an function in c as a linked list but i can't understand how convert it to a linked list.

My Question is how to convert an linked list to an dynamic array. This function adds elements to an linked list i want to be able to add elements to an dynamic array. i don't know if the struct blockhead_node is right like i said i'm still learning c. I do not understand dynamic arrays so i'm trying to create an program that uses them so i may understand them better. i want to create an add function that adds elements to the front or end of the list. This is what i have:

```
//this struct i'm trying to use for dynamic array
struct blockhead_node
{
    float x, y;
    float dx, dy;
    long color;
    int size;      // slots used so far
    int capacity;  // total available slots
    int *data;     // array of integers we're storing

};
//this struct is for the linked list
struct blockhead_node
{
    float x,y;
    float dx, dy;
    long color;
    int size;
    struct blockhead_node * next;
};

void add(struct blockhead_node ** blockhead_list) // double pointer because we can't modify the list it self

{

    while((*blockhead_list)!=NULL)
    {

        blockhead_list=&(*blockhead_list)->next;

    }

    (*blockhead_list) = (struct blockhead_node*) malloc(sizeof(struct blockhead_node));
    (*blockhead_list)->x = rand()%screen_width + (*blockhead_list)->size;
    //(*blockhead_list)->x = 400;
    //
    //look up how to create an random floating point number
    //
    (*blockhead_list)->dx = ((float)rand()/(float)(10000));
    (*blockhead_list)->y = rand()%screen_height + (*blockhead_list)->size;
    (*blockhead_list)->dy = ((float)rand()/(float)(10000));
    (*blockhead_list)->size = rand()%100;
    (*blockhead_list)->next = NULL;
    if((*blockhead_list)->x + (*blockhead_list)->size > screen_width)
    {
        (*blockhead_list)->x = screen_width - (*blockhead_list)->size;
    }
    if((*blockhead_list)->y + (*blockhead_list)->size > screen_height)
    {
        (*blockhead_list)->y = screen_height - (*blockhead_list)->size;
    }


}
```

Comment: First, your linked list code needs some work. Do you want to _append_ to the tail of the list [as your first `while` loop implies], or do you want to _insert_ at the head of the list? Are you wanting a dynamic array because the list code is not working or do you _really_ want to convert this to a dynamic array [your title and question body conflict on this point]? And, do you want an array of your `struct`s or just an array of the `data` elements and the `struct` controls the dynamic array? I presume you'd want an array of `struct`s.

Comment: the code works i want to rewrite the program above so that it uses dynamic arrays ( using realloc and free ) instead of a linked list. i know i'm still learning c. i want to add a node at the first point of the array. basically, i want to do that same thing i'm doing there but with an dynamic array. i'm working to understand linked list and dynamic arrays.

Comment: Your code, as _posted_ does _not_ set the _next_ value, or even show it in the `struct`, so start by editing your question and post the better/working code. Adding to a linked list at the _front_ is very easy. Inserting at the front of a dynamic array is very _slow_ because each time you do it, you have to copy all previous elements to make room (e.g. `arr[5] = arr[4]; arr[4] = arr[3]; arr[3] = arr[2]; arr[2] = arr[1]; arr[1] = arr[0];`) so you can now fill `arr[0]`. _Appending_ is much simpler and _faster_ because this copying isn't needed.

Comment: i edited the struct that's why next isn't in there. i was trying to make struct really for dynamic arrays.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is create an add function that adds elements to an list I've done it in linked list now i'm trying to do it with an dynamic array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a dynamic array is not much different than using a linked-list. The primary difference is you are responsible for keeping track of `size` and `realloc` your `data` array when `size == capacity` (or when `capacity == 0` for a new stuct).

Other than that you are either allocating per-node with a linked-list, whereas with a dynamic array you can allocate in a more efficient manner by allocating by some multiple of the current `capacity` when `size == capacity`. For arrays of completely unknown size you can either start with `capacity = 2` or `8` and then either increase by some multiple (e.g. `3/2` or `2`, etc..) or some fixed amount (`8, 16, etc..`) each time a reallocation is needed. I generally just double the current capacity, e.g. starting a `2`, reallocating storage in `data` for `4, 8, 16, 32, ...` integers as more numbers are added to `data`. You can do it any way you like -- *as long as you keep track of your* `size` *and* `capacity`.

A short example may help. Let's start with just a simple struct where `data` is the only dynamic member we are concerned about. For example:

```
#define CAP 2       /* initial capacity for new struct */

typedef struct {
    size_t size,
        capacity;
    int *data;
} blkhd_node;
```

Where `size` is your `"slots used so far"` and `capacity` is your `"total available slots"` and `data` your `"array of integers we're storing"`.

The `add` function is fairly trivial. All you need to do is check whether you need to `realloc` (e.g. this is a struct not used yet where `capacity == 0` or all the slots are used and `size == capacity`). Since `realloc` can be used for both new and resizing the allocation, it is all you need. The scheme is simple, if this is a new struct, we will allocate for `CAP` number of `int`, otherwise if `size == capacity` we will allocated `2 * capacity` number of `int`.

*Whenever we `realloc` we do so with a temporary pointer!* Why? When `realloc` fails it returns `NULL`. If you `realloc` with the original pointer (e.g. `data = realloc (data, newsize);` and `NULL` is returned, you overwrite your original pointer address for `data` with `NULL` and your ability to reach (or `free`) the original block of memory is lost -- creating a memory leak. By using a temporary pointer, we can validate whether `realloc` succeeds **before** we assign the new address to `data`. Importantly, if `realloc` does fail -- then our existing integers pointed to by `data` are still fine, so we are free to use our original allocation in the event of `realloc` failure. Important to remember.

We also need a way to indicate success/failure of or `add` function. Here, you are not adding a new node, so returning a pointer to a new node isn't an option. In this case a simple `int` return of `0` for failure of `1` for success is just as good as anything else.

With that, an `add` function could be as simple as:

```
int add (blkhd_node *b, int v)
{
    /* realloc if (1) new struct or (2) size == capacity */
    if (!b->capacity || b->size == b->capacity) {
        size_t newsize;
        if (!b->capacity)                   /* new stuct, set size = CAP */
            newsize = CAP;
        else if (b->size == b->capacity)    /* otherwise double size */
            newsize = b->capacity * 2;
        /* alway realloc with a temporary pointer */
        void *tmp = realloc (b->data, newsize * sizeof *b->data);
        if (!tmp) {     /* validate reallocation */
            perror ("realloc_b->data");
            return 0;   /* return failure */ 
        }
        b->data = tmp;          /* assign new block of mem to data */
        b->capacity = newsize;  /* set capacity to newsize */
    }

    b->data[b->size++] = v;     /* set data value to v */

    return 1;   /* return success */
}
```

**Note:** since you are initializing your struct and both `size` and `capacity` will be `0`, you can dispense with separate checks for `capacity == 0` and `size == capacity` and use a *ternary* to set `newsize`. This is arguably the less-readable way to go and a good compiler will optimize both identically, but for sake of completeness, you could replace the code setting `newsize` with:

```
    /* realloc if (1) new struct or (2) size == capacity */
    if (b->size == b->capacity) {
        /* set newsize */
        size_t newsize = b->capacity ? b->capacity * 2 : CAP;
```

Given the option, your choice should always be for the more readable and maintainable code. You do your job, and let the compiler worry about the rest.

(you can do a dynamic array of `struct blockhead_node` in **exactly** the same way -- just account for the number of structs you have in the array in addition to the `size, capacity` for `data` in each -- that is left to you)

So, let's see if our scheme of originally allocating for `2-int` will allow us to `add` `100-int` to our `data` array with a short example putting it altogether:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CAP 2       /* initial capacity for new struct */

typedef struct {
    size_t size,
        capacity;
    int *data;
} blkhd_node;

int add (blkhd_node *b, int v)
{
    /* realloc if (1) new struct or (2) size == capacity */
    if (!b->capacity || b->size == b->capacity) {
        size_t newsize;
        if (!b->capacity)                   /* new stuct, set size = CAP */
            newsize = CAP;
        else if (b->size == b->capacity)    /* otherwise double size */
            newsize = b->capacity * 2;
        /* alway realloc with a temporary pointer */
        void *tmp = realloc (b->data, newsize * sizeof *b->data);
        if (!tmp) {     /* validate reallocation */
            perror ("realloc_b->data");
            return 0;   /* return failure */ 
        }
        b->data = tmp;          /* assign new block of mem to data */
        b->capacity = newsize;  /* set capacity to newsize */
    }

    b->data[b->size++] = v;     /* set data value to v */

    return 1;   /* return success */
}

void prndata (blkhd_node *b)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < b->size; i++) {
        if (i && i % 10 == 0)
            putchar ('\n');
        printf (" %3d", b->data[i]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}

int main (void) {

    blkhd_node b = { .size = 0 };   /* declare/initialize struct */

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)   /* add 100 data values */
        if (!add (&b, i + 1))
            break;  /* don't exit, all prior data still good */

    /* output results */
    printf ("\nsize     : %zu\ncapacity : %zu\n\n", b.size, b.capacity);
    prndata (&b);

    free (b.data);  /* don't forget to free what you allocate */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/dynarrayint

size     : 100
capacity : 128

   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/dynarrayint
==12589== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12589== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12589== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12589== Command: ./bin/dynarrayint
==12589==

size     : 100
capacity : 128

   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
==12589==
==12589== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12589==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12589==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 1,016 bytes allocated
==12589==
==12589== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12589==
==12589== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12589== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much. i'm going to put this in a word doc so i can analyze and make sure i understand what you mean exactly. that was very detailed so it helps me after reading a few i actually understood that a bit better.

Comment: Glad it helps. There really isn't any mystery to handling dynamic allocation for whatever you need. The key is making sure you are allocating for the number of elements you need *times the size of each element*. Where I use `sizeof *b->data` that is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`. Why `b->size` is `int*` so `*b->size` is just `int`. If you use `sizeof` with the dereferenced pointer, you will never get the type-size wrong `:)`

Comment: Also, the reason I chose `blkhd_node *b` as the parameter to `add` rather than `blkhd_node b` is as struct size grow, you don't want to have to pass the entire struct by value as a parameter (some struct may contain 1000 members). Simply passing a pointer is much more efficient.

Comment: okay, i understand it also helps because i had no idea where to start as of now i have an idea of where to continue. So, i may learn and understand. thank you

Comment: i do have one more question how do i account for the x and y so i may render the blockheads to the screen?

Comment: You can simply add them to the struct and give them values in `add`. Just add additional parameters for them, e.g. `int add (blkhd_node *b, int v, float x, float y)`. If they are added sometime later, then just create a `void setxy (blkhd_node *b, float x, float y) { b->x = x; b->y = y; }` function to set them whenever/wherever needed. (I would also recommend changing all `float` to `double` if accuracy and rounding error could be a problem)

Comment: i can see the double and adding in the parameter but i'm not full sure here but for example to place by mouse position the idea i'm coming up with is a for loop

Comment: Well first, if you enclose your code in *backticks* in the comments here, it will be formatted as code. "place by mouse position"? Presumably, you mean using the `x, y` parameters of the struct. The cursor positioning is a whole different ball game. (requiring a curses library for text screen, or a graphics toolkit for X or windows). The salient question is does each struct `x, y` hold just that one position, or are you thinking about an array of your struct so that you have many, many potential different mouse positions? (the array of struct route)?

Comment: for (int c = 0; c >= bkhd_list; c++)
      reallc(bkhd_list + 1 = bkhd_list; //adding memory 
 
   bkhd_list[-1] = mx; //add a bkhd to the end of the list

Comment: that slight went over my head. um... i planed to have one add function add nodes and random to the screen and another add one node and the mouse position. i have the graphics downloaded and placed in the file.

Comment: Sure, there is nothing wrong with maintaining a linked-list struct where each node contains the dynamic array. That's fine. Is that what you are attempting? Also, is this you [How to remove elements from an dynamic array by mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53665477/how-to-remove-elements-from-an-dynamic-array-by-mouse-position)

Comment: For actually positioning on the screen, look at [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html) or `cairo` in [GTK+ 3 Reference Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/). (you will use cairo on gtk, Qt is also a C++ option) There is also SDL2 and OpenGL (for blitting graphics to the screen) There are good tutorials for each.

Comment: Nope, friend were working on the same project. I guess she got stuck to .  I'm using bkhd_list in sub for array list i'm just lazy to change the name.

Comment: I'm using SDL2, I assume the for loop will give me the ability for placing nodes at mouse positions on the screen?

Comment: Chuckling. The best advise I can give regarding your data handling implementation and your user interface is *Always keep your implementation and interface separate!* Meaning, your data handling functions should not also contain calls to put that information on the screen. Your interface should use separate functions entirely that make use of your `bkhd_list` data to do the drawing while the code responsible for maintaining `bkhd_list` should remain separate. When you starting looking into drawing to the screen, expect an equal or more amount of learning.

Comment: And yes, you are correct. You will use a single loop (that may call many separate functions) to update your screen in SDL2. Remember SDL2 is only responsible for the drawing part, (it will have no idea what it did during the last iteration and will only be able to update your screen with new information). There are good SDL2 tutorials, e.g. [Lazy Foo Productions](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/)

Comment: Yeah, we got it done with linked list but dynamic arrays has me stumped. I agree, i have them  separate just trying to understand how to place the mouse_x and Mouse_y position into the array so the render can render it to the screen.

Comment: that website has helped a bit.

Comment: He has SDL and SDL2 tutorials as well as OpenGL. When I say it will be equally as much work to digest graphic drawing as handling linked-lists and dynamic arrays -- it will. There are no shortcuts. This is why good programmers get paid the big bucks -- if it was easy anyone could do it. The reason it is C/C++ is speed. You can cludge an implementation in another language -- but you always run up against the same limitation -- processing the graphic changes take longer than screen refresh allows. That's why much is written in C.